# ListActivity não funciona Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Eu tenho uma Activity com um botão chamando uma List Activity. Essa ListActivity cria rapidamente uma lista de string, só quero mostrar essa lista na tela e exibir em um Toast o item selecionado.

Mas não está funcionando! Segue o código da classe Lista

```
public class Lista extends ListActivity{

    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] itens = new String[]{"João","josé","pedro",};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itens);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String item = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicou em: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

O que está faltando?

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado no console? O método chega a ser chamado? (coloque o debug ou um sysout para verificar)

Se uma melhor descrição do cenário fica difícil ajudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código **Java** é [*case-sensitive*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive), isso quer dizer que **Double** é diferente de **double**, **String** é diferente **string** e assim por diante.

Logo, você tem um erro no seu código já que o método **OnCreate** não existe na classe `ListActivity` (e por sua vez, na `Activity`) que foi herdada e acontece que ela nunca é executada em sua classe. Portanto, você só precisa alterar o erro de grafia para [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) na assinatura do método:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

É sempre bom utilizar a anotação `@Override`, assim garante que o método que está querendo redefinir realmente existe na **super** classe.

Comment: Entendi. Bom, sou iniciante no java, neste momento não posso testar isso, mas vou validar sua resposta o quanto antes.